# Using bib2gls with rmarkdown fails to render glossary

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I'd like to use the `bib2gls` latex package in my rmarkdown document to insert a list of acronyms from a .bib file when I knit to a pdf document.

**Doesn't work:**

Using a .bib file to store my acronyms. Example:

abbreviations.bib file:

```
@abbreviation{ecoli, 
short={E.~coli},
long={Escherichia coli}
}


@abbreviation{raustralis ,
short ={R.~ australis},
long={Rickettsia australis}
}
```

preamble.tex

```tex
% fixes problem with glossaries causing mathspec
% to return an error asking for amsmath to be loaded first    
\makeatletter 
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother

% using bib2gls
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,style=index]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={abbreviations},selection={all}]
```

rmarkdown file:

```r
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
title: "mwe"

---

## R Markdown

This is the first instance \gls{ecoli}, \gls{raustralis}. This is the second instance: \gls{ecoli}, \gls{raustralis}.

\printunsrtglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=abbreviations]
```

The output when I knit the rmarkdown documents looks like:
[image]

What works:

Removing `\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={abbreviations},selection={all}]` and adding my entries into the preamble.

```tex
% using bib2gls
\usepackage[abbreviations,style=index]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newabbreviation{ecoli}{E.~coli}{Escherichia coli}
\newabbreviation{raustralis}{R.~australis}{Rickettsia australis}
```

[image]

I'd like to use the separate .bib file in the first approach if possible. Unless there is a better approach to do this in R. Session info is below:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that `bib2gls` requires an additional program to be run, which extracts the glossary entries from the `bib` file, but `rmarkdown` does not know about that. In general, if you want to do something more complicated on the LaTeX side, there is a good chance that `latexmk` already knows how to do that. I am not sure if this is here the case, c.f. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400325/latexmkrc-for-bib2gls. However, you can give it a try using

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")
```
````